# Setting up a git web development environment

Tags: php, git

The structure I'm trying to setup is as follows:

- `/public_html`       repository ("live") what the users see, contains custom
                     uploaded files (e.g. user gallery images, etc, these are ignored with .gitignore)
- `/stable`            repository containing the latest stable source for the project (minus the ignored files)
- `/public_html/dev`   development environment, where only myself and another developer will edit files in, test online directly from this folder.

Whenever any changes are made, they are done so in the `/dev` repository, and changes are pushed up to `/stable` which I would like to create a hook to automatically update the `/public_html` repository with the latest stable files.

#### Development area

As I understand git development is usually cloned and done in a local environment, but due to licensing restrictions on the software we use, and it requiring a very specific server setup, doing local development is not an option. We therefore need to have a central development area to test changes.

My questions are as follows:

1. How could I achieve the above structure?
2. What needs to be a base repository and what does not (as I understand `push` to a non-base repository can be troublesome.)
3. Any improvements/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/stable` should be a bare repository.

`/public_html` should not be a repository at all - instead, you should use `git archive` [or similar](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) in your hook to export files from the `/stable` repository into `/public_html`.

Ideally, I'd suggest not putting your `dev` repository in `/public_html` - it'd be better off in a separate document root of its own, that way you don't run into potential issues from path collisions etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. `git archive` is new to me. Would this basically copy *all* indexed files to the public_html directory rather than those that have just been updated? Is there any performance penalties rather than just doing either `pull` `push` `fetch` on a public_html repository (assuming I did make that a repository)?

Comment: The reason you don't want to make `public_html` a repository is because it means that you then have a `.git` directory in your web root, which means that someone can theoretically access all of your private version control information (commit messages, source code of files, etc). If you'd like, you can click on the "or similar" link in my post to get a solution that would be more efficient than archive, via an explicit workdir for a repo elsewhere.